# Problem with controlling size of image inside a Card

Tags: html, class, card

```
<div class="row">
<div class="column">
  <!--<h2 align="center">Column 1</h2>-->
   <img src="rec_50th_anniversary.jpg"   style="height:40px"  width="75px"  class=" card- 
     img-top  center" alt="anniversary">
<p align="center">My Chapter held its <br> 50th Anniversary celebration in October 
 2021</p>
```

The above code displays however when I adjust the height and weight of the card it does not respond.  It keeps the same size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is happening because you declared the width out of the  tag, try `style="height:40px; width: 75px"`

Comment: Appreciate the response.  It worked.  Looks like I had one of those "duh" moments